# More tags to kill?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

We're managed to kill off the free tag over the weekend (and without annoying anyone too much)

[conference](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conference) and [registration](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/registration) might be good targets - both mean nothing, and together have less than 40 questions (unlike the epic snipehunt that was the free tag)

Yes, no or "no don't hurt the poor unloved tags" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah [registration](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/registration) is all over the place, with questions from software activation to software registration to even DLL registration(!). Definitely needs to go.

[conference](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conference) doesn't add much either

Comment: registration seems to be dead.